# Object-fit: cover - is not working with video tags without border-radius

Tags: html, css, html5-video

I am facing a problem, that I cannot make `object-fit: cover;` work with video tag because it is overlays outside the parent container, even if I use `object-fit: cover;`

Only one solution works: add a border-radius with some value, like:

`border-radius: 10px;`
to the video tag css.

Working example:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qmrvLB
Comment in or out `border-radius: 10px;` line to see what is my problem.

Comment: So use `border-radius: 1px;` ... no one will see that radius

Comment: this was my idea also

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If using `border-radius: 1px;` (and no one will see that radius) feels too hacky, use a `wrapper`

```css
body {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

video {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <video poster="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/polina.jpg" id="bgvid" playsinline autoplay muted loop>
<source src="http://thenewcode.com/assets/videos/polina.webm" type="video/webm">
<source src="http://thenewcode.com/assets/videos/polina.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

video {
  object-fit: contain;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <video poster="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/4273/polina.jpg" id="bgvid" playsinline autoplay muted loop>
<source src="http://thenewcode.com/assets/videos/polina.webm" type="video/webm">
<source src="http://thenewcode.com/assets/videos/polina.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).